# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for integrand with jump discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a Riemann-integrable function such that at $c \in (a,b)$:

$\lim \limits_{x \to c^-} f(x)$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to c^+} f(x)$ exist but are not equal. If we define $F(x) := \int_{a}^{x}f$, is it true that:

$\lim \limits_{x \to c^-} \frac{F(x) - F(c)}{x-c} = \lim \limits_{x \to c^-} f(x)$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to c^+} \frac{F(x) - F(c)}{x-c} = \lim \limits_{x \to c^+} f(x)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to show that 
$$\lim_{x\to c^+}\frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x).$$
Let $A=\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)$. For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-A|<\epsilon$ for any $x\in(c,c+\delta)$. So for $x\in(c,c+\delta)$,
$$\left|\frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c}-A\right|=\left|\frac{\int_c^x (f(t)-A)\,dt}{x-c}\right|\leq \frac{\int_c^x|f(t)-A|\,dt}{x-c}\leq \epsilon,$$
which gives the desired result.